# "tunX" interface device sequence is incrementing with every "ssh" connection

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel, interface

We use `ssh -w` connection to create tunnels from client workstations to the server. `-w` creates a tunnel interface for that particular `ssh` connection. On the server side I noticed every time `ssh` re-connects interface sequence number (circled in red) gets incremented.

[image]

My concern (forgive me if it is stupid) is if this ever incrementing sequence can cause issues if there is some sort of limit e.g. what if sequence only goes up to 255 or something like that.